# How to discover services deployed on kubernetes from the outside?

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

The `User Microservice` is deployed on kubernetes.

The `Order Microservice` is not deployed on kubernetes,  but registered with Eureka.

***My questions:***

How can `Order Microservice` discover and access `User Microservice` through the Eureka??

Answer (score 1):

First lets take a look at the problem itself: 
If you use an overlay network as Kubernetes CNI, the problem is that it creates an isolated Network thats not reachable from the outside (e.g. Flannel). If you have a network like that one solution would be to move the eureka server into kubernetes so eureka can reach the service in Kubernetes and the service outside of Kubernetes.

Another solution would be to tell eureka where it can find the service instead of auto discovery but for that you also need to make the service externally available with a *Service* of type NodePort, HostPort or LoadBalancer or with an *ingress* and I'm not sure its possible, but 11.2 in the following doc could be worth a look [Eureka Client Discovery](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html).

The third solution would be to use a CNI thats not using an overlay network like [Romana](https://github.com/romana/romana) which will make the service external routable by default.

Comment: Thanks , but how does OrderService find the external-ip of UserService through Eureka?

Comment: You call the service through eureka so order service doesn't need to know the external ip, the call is something like: http://{eurekaServer}/{servicename} the service resolution is done by eureka.

Comment: The service is registering with kubernetes pod IP address and port instead of service IP address,  so I cannot call the service through eureka.

Comment: Have you tried to set *eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone* as suggested?

Comment: Yes.  Service have be registered in the eureka, but cannot be accessed.

Comment: Have you set the default zone to the externally accesible address created through the Service/ Ingress? If you did that i guess only options 1 or 3 remain.